# What components of a machine affect the machine code produced given a C++ file input?

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, executable, machine-code

I wrote this question [What affects generated machine code at each step of the compilation process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72480202/what-affects-generated-machine-code-at-each-step-of-the-compilation-process?noredirect=1#comment128038281_72480202)? and realized that is was much too broad. So I will try to ask each component of it in a different question.

The first question I will ask is, given an arbitrary C++ file what affects the resulting executable binary file it produces? So far I understand each of the following play a role

- The CPU architecture like x86_64, ARM64, Power PC, Microblaze, ect.
- The kernel of a machine like Linux kernel v5.18, v5.17, a Windows Kernel version, a Mac kernel version ect.
- The operating system such as Debian, CentOS, Windows 7, Windows 10, Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Mac OS X Sierra.

  - Not sure what the OS changes on top of the kernel changes.
- Finally the tools used to compile, assembly and link. Things like GCC, Clang, Visual Studio (VS), GNU assembler, GNU compiler, VS Compiler, VS linker, ect.

So the 2 questions I have from this are

- Is there some other component that I left out that affects how the final executable looks like?
- And does the operating system play a role in affecting the final executable machine code? Because I thought it would all be due to the kernel.

Comment: A tool-chain (compiler, linker runtime-support other tools) has a "host" and a "target".  The "host" is the system it is running on and the "target" is the system it is to produce executable code for (host and target can be the same).  eg you can have a tool-chain running on linux (host) targeting AMD64-Android (target).  For example if you build the gcc tool-chain there are pages of configuration details to be setup to support your host and target environments.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am aware of tool-chains and cross compiling. My follow up would be what determines the tool-chains output? Surely the tool chain must know what CPU architecture to build for. It probably needs to know what kernel to build for. I'm guessing the OS might need to be known, unsure? And surely different tool-chain tools will produce different results even when targeting the same CPU/Kernel/OS combination.

Comment: When you build the tool-chain you tell it the host, target and about 100 other settings.

Comment: I haven't seen many other options in my experience besides the CPU/Kernel/OS ones. Which other options have you seen?

Comment: Configuration options before building gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: also the extended instruction set, such as vector operations, different revs of x86_64 have different capabilities, you can tell the compiler what to target

Comment: @pm100 yeah those I have seen I guess I was lumping those under the CPU topic.

Comment: Some may disagree, but I think this question - specifically "what am I missing?" still lacks focus.  The code itself affects the binary, of course.  That wasn't mentioned.  Command-line parameters passed to the tools, such as what optimizations are used and what conditions should make it fail.   Environment variables can change a binary.  If there's debugging info, the names of the source files and layout of the filesystem can affect the final executable.

Comment: You forgot about memory and data.  On some platforms, there may be different kinds of memory:  read-only and read-write memory.  The executable (in embedded systems), is often placed in Read-Only memory and maybe copied to Read/Write memory.  Constants can be placed in Read-Only memory and variables (stack, heap) placed into Read/Write memory.  Many executable formats are split into `regions` depending on how the data is handled.  The compiler and linker need to know the memory layout of the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main one I think you're missing is the [Application Binary Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).  Part of the ABI is the calling convention, which determines certain properties of register usage and parameter passing, so these directly affect the generated machine code.

The kernel has a loader, and that loader works with file formats, like ELF or PE.  These influence the machine code by determining the layout of the process and how the program's code & data are loaded into memory, and how the machine code instructions access data and other code.  Some environments want position independent code, for example, which affects some of the machine code instructions.

---

> The CPU architecture like x86_64, ARM64, Power PC, Microblaze, ect.

Yes.  The instruction set architecture defines the available instructions to use, which in turn define the available CPU registers and how they can be used as well as and sizes of things like pointers.

> The kernel of a machine like Linux kernel v5.18, v5.17, a Windows Kernel version, a Mac kernel version ect.

Not really.  The operating system choice influences the ABI, which is very relevant, though.

> The operating system such as Debian, CentOS, Windows 7, Windows 10, Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Mac OS X Sierra.

The operating system usually dictates the ABI, which is important.

> the tools used to compile, assembly and link. Things like GCC, Clang, Visual Studio (VS), GNU assembler, GNU compiler, VS Compiler, VS linker, ect.

Of course, different tools produce some different machine code, sometimes the differences are equivalent, though some tools produce better machine code than others for some inputs.

Comment: Interesting, so if two machines are identical in every aspect CPU, kernel, kernel version, and compiler tools and the only thing that differs is their OS, Centos vs Debian, they can produce different machine code? Because the ABI is dictated by the OS and not the kernel?

Comment: I'm not sure what the distinction is between OS and kernel.

Comment: I guess the kernel is really just a subset of the OS so maybe it does not make sense to distinguish them in this sense. I thought I needed to be specific since some OSes use the same kernel and version but really they are just using the same subset.

Comment: The kernel dictates the syscall ABI (which registers are used to pass which syscall arguments). The glibc (which is part of the OS) dictates a calling convention when it is linked to a program. However the internal ABI of a program can be choosen freely. E.g. C++ could use a different calling convention as C. That is the reason for the need of `extern "C"` declarations.

Comment: @JakobStark, yes, the syscall ABI; I suppose that would apply to compiler output if the compilers inline syscalls one way or another -- does that happen?